# Files disappearing after mv command

Tags: files, directory, mv

I trying to learn how to move files around. I made some test files and directories to practice with. When I try to move a file from one directory to the other, the file just completely disappears.

I use "sudo mv testfile2.txt /Jupiter

Jupiter is one of my directories. It leaves the one its in but never shows up in Jupiter. I am at a loss of what to do. I have been using my Linux plus study guide and have already hit a brick wall with this. thank you.

Comment: I suspect you meant ./Jupiter (ie. Jupiter in the current or $PWD directory).  You moved it to /Jupiter - ie. Jupiter in the / directory (which if not a directory, you renamed testfile2.txt to /Jupiter with the command.

Comment: That helped... I guess I was renaming it over and over again. I put the (.) infront of the / and that helped. thank you so much!

Comment: If you're happy with the answer, please consider accepting the answer below.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you meant ./Jupiter (ie. Jupiter in the current or $PWD directory).

You moved it to /Jupiter - ie. Jupiter in the / directory (which if directory named /Jupiter didn't already exist, you renamed testfile2.txt to /Jupiter with your command).